# PHP/Codeigniter - For Loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, for-loop

**Update: Complete Controller**
the code below only produces the thumbnail of the first image and successfully uploads all the other images. the problem that i am facing is that the other images do get uploaded but their thumbnails aren't.

```
<?php
class Upload extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->upload_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../uploads');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_view', array('error' => ''));
    }

    function start()
    {
        // var_dump($_FILES); die();
        $config['upload_path'] = $this->upload_path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);            
        $status = $this->upload->do_multi_upload();
        for($i=0;$i<count($status);$i++)
        {
            $conf = array(
                'source_image' => $status[$i]['full_path'],
                'new_image' => $this->upload_path . '/thumbs',
                'maintain_ratio' => true,
                'width' => 200,
                'height' => 200
            );

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $conf);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            $this->image_lib->clear();
        }

        if (!$status)        
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload_view', $error);
        }    
        else
        {
            var_dump($status);
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: That's not enough code. Seems to me that the destination images are being overwritten because you're not defining filenames.

Comment: Aah! Problem solved. all i needed to do was reinitialize the $conf variable.

Answer (score 0):

Load the library prior to starting the loop and without passing parameters to it.
Then, for each of the elements in $status do this:

```
$this->image_lib->initialize($conf);
```

... and you don't need to use `clear()` afterwards.

Comment: I'm referring to the $conf array that you've shown in the description. If you've removed/renamed it, or if you execute this prior to defining it - yes, it will give an "Undefined variable" error. :)